# Uses of volatile without synchronization

Tags: java, volatile

Knowing that

> Reads and writes are [atomic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) for all variables declared volatile

**Question1:** Can this be understood as if

```
private volatile int x = 0;
```

`x++;` operation is atomic?

And that

> Marking variable volatile does not eliminate all need to synchronize
>   atomic actions, because [memory consistency errors are still possible.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html)

**Question2:** I wonder under what circumstances (if any) it is possible to see a variable marked `volatile` and not see any methods of blocks marked synchronized (that attempt to access/ modify the variable)?

In other words, should all variables that need to be protected from concurrent modification be marked `volatile`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The volatile only gives you additional visibility guarantees, atomic writes/reads for longs/doubles (otherwise not guaranteed by the JLS, yes) and some memory order guarantees. **No** synchronization (it is possible though to build synchronization blocks starting with just volatile - [Dekker's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dekker%27s_algorithm) )
So no, it does not help you with `x++` - that's still a read, inc and write and needs some form of synchronization.

One example of volatile is the famous double-checked locking, where we avoid synchronization most of the time because the ordering guarantees are all we need:

```
private volatile Helper helper = null;
public Helper getHelper() {
    if (helper == null) {
        synchronized(this) {
            if (helper == null) {
                helper = new Helper();
            }
        }
    }
    return helper;
}
```

An example where there's absolutely no synchronization involved, is a simple exit flag, here it's not about ordering guarantees but only about the guaranteed visibility

```
public volatile boolean exit = false;
public void run() {
   while (!exit) doStuff();
   // exit when exit set to true
}
```

If another thread sets `exit = true` the other thread doing the while loop is guaranteed to see the update - without volatile it may not.

Answer (score 7):

> x++; operation is atomic?

No.  This reduces to `x = x + 1`.  The read of `x` is atomic, and the write to `x` is atomic, but `x = x + 1` as a whole is not atomic.

> I wonder under what circumstances (if any) it is possible to see a variable marked volatile and not see any methods of blocks marked synchronized (that attempt to access/ modify the variable)?

Well, there are all kinds of approaches to concurrency that don't use `synchronized`.  There's a wide variety of other locking utilities in Java, and lock-free algorithms that still require things like `volatile`: `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is a specific example, though it makes extensive use of "magical" `compareAndSet` atomics.

Answer (score 0):

As a quickly testable example that may illustrate the previous answers, this yields always a final count of 8:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;


public class ThreadTest_synchronize {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ThreadTest_synchronize tt = new ThreadTest_synchronize ();
    try {
        tt.go();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void go() throws InterruptedException{

    MyRunnable t = new MyRunnable();
    Thread myThread_1 = new Thread( t, "t1");
    Thread myThread_2 = new Thread( t, "t2");
    myThread_1.start();
    myThread_2.start();
    myThread_1.join();
    myThread_2.join();
    System.out.println("Processing count="+t.getCount());       

}

private class MyRunnable implements Runnable{

    private AtomicInteger count=new AtomicInteger(0);

    @Override
    public  void run() {
        for(int i=1; i< 5; i++){
            doSomething(i);
            count.getAndAdd(1);
        }           
    }


    public AtomicInteger getCount() {
        return this.count;
    }


    private void doSomething(int i) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(i*300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}       

}
```

while this generally does not:

```
public class ThreadTest_volatile {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ThreadTest_volatile tt = new ThreadTest_volatile ();
    try {
        tt.go();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void go() throws InterruptedException{

    MyRunnable t = new MyRunnable();
    Thread myThread_1 = new Thread( t, "t1");
    Thread myThread_2 = new Thread( t, "t2");
    myThread_1.start();
    myThread_2.start();
    myThread_1.join();
    myThread_2.join();
    System.out.println("Processing count="+t.getCount());       

}

private class MyRunnable implements Runnable{

    private volatile int count = 0;


    @Override
    public  void run() {
        for(int i=1; i< 5; i++){
            doSomething(i);
            count++;
        }

    }

    private  int add(int count){
        return ++count;
    }


    public int getCount(){
        return count;
    }

    private void doSomething(int i) {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(i*300);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


}
```