# Is it possible to use volatile variables to allow consistent write-only synchronisation?

Tags: java, synchronization, locking, synchronized, volatile

Is it possible to use volatile variables to allow consistent write-only synchronisation?

This is the code:

```
public class Controller {

    Container cont = new Container();
    ...

    public Object get(){
        if(!cont.isLocked()){
            return cont.getObject(); //many threads can read at the same time
        }
        else synchronized(cont){
            return cont.getObject(); //threads wait until write is finished
        }
    }

    public void set(Object o){
        synchronized(cont){
            cont.lock();
            cont.setObject(o);
            cont.unlock();
        }
    }
}

public class Container {
    private volatile boolean lock = false;
    private Object data;

    public Container(){
            }

    public void lock() {
        lock = true;
    }

    public void unlock() {
        lock = false;
    }

    public boolean isLocked() {
        return lock;
    }

    public void setObject(Object o) {
        data = o;
    }

    public Object getObject() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Will it work, or will it break, what do you think?

Comment: It looks good to me.  But if you wanted to be sure, you could actually test this by introducing delays into `setObject` and `getObject`; plus a few judicious debugging messages.  +1 for producing an SSCCE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may/will break. Example of execution:

- T1: `if(!cont.isLocked())` returns true
- T2: `set(someObject)`
- T1: `return cont.getObject();` returns an old version

Even worse, since you don't have a proper happens-before relationship between T2 and T1, `cont.getObject()` may return the a reference to the new object created by T2, but pointing to an inconsistent/not-fully-constructed object.

You have a typical check-then-act problem.

Why don't you just use a volatile reference to your object?

```
public class Controller {

    private volatile Object obj = new Object();

    public Object get(){ return obj; }
    public void set(Object o){ obj = o; }
}
```

That would be thread safe.

Comment: That would probably be sufficient - but you should explain your real goal because your example is unnecessarily complex - so either your actual use case has additional constraints that you have not mentioned or you should make yoru class a lot simpler.

Comment: Do you really think it can be done simpler? I mean, I can't just synchronize on `Object data`, that would defeat the purpose of non-synchronized reads...

Comment: @Marcus What I meant is that the code snippet in my answer does what you intended to do but in a much simpler way. Is there a reason why you had a complex design in the first place?

Comment: Well, as I said I can't just synchronize on `Object data` because I want to read without slow synchronisation...and IMO also `synchronized(cont)` must be called when writing. Or do you think that using just a volatile object will also synchronize it consistently?

Comment: @Marcus volatile will ensure visibility and reference assignment is atomic so yes it should be fine. But then your `Controller` just becomes a simple version of an `AtomicReference` so you might as well just use that instead...

Comment: Ah, so I will use volatile fields to enable fast reads and just synchronize the writes. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Marcus you don't need to synchronize the writes if the field is volatile.

Comment: But here the answerer says it's needed: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11385864/2012947. What do you think?

Comment: @Marcus in that situation synchronized is required because there is more than one operation (`if (a == null) { a = new A(); return a; }`) - so because there is a check then an assignment, volatile guarantees are not enough. In my example it is a simple assignment which is atomic so no need for synchronized.

Comment: @Marcus Same thing with the example on `x++` - that statement effectively represents a read, increment and write. So three operations which need to be enclosed in a synchronized block to be atomic. There again volatile is not enough.

Comment: Alright, so when I have 2 volatile objects within the `Container` and want to change them consistently, then I need synchronization (to make a block "atomic" so to speak). Okey, one could say that in this case I also need to synchronize the reads (to get atomic reads). However in my case I will only change 1 field, the other remains constant, so I'll set the 1 field as volatile and the other as final. Thx :)

Comment: @Marcus If you need to update the two fields atomically then volatile won't be enough. Have you considered using a ReadWriteLock? It is designed to deal with scenarios like yours (from what I understand).