# Use of volatile without synchronized for lazy singleton in Android Studio project template "Login Activity"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, thread-safety, singleton

I am learning Android and have been looking through the base project templates provided by Android Studio 3.4.1. The one called "Login Activity" (accessible via New Project...) sets up an implementation with a Repository class in LoginRepository.java

```java
    public class LoginRepository {

        private static volatile LoginRepository instance;

        private LoginDataSource dataSource;

        private LoggedInUser user = null;

        // private constructor : singleton access
        private LoginRepository(LoginDataSource dataSource) {
            this.dataSource = dataSource;
        }

        public static LoginRepository getInstance(LoginDataSource dataSource) {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new LoginRepository(dataSource);
            }

            return instance;
        }

        // other methods excluded for simplicity
    }
}
```

[link to android.com description](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/templates#LoginActivity)
[link to another question with more of the app code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55787064/how-to-implement-asynctask-in-login-activity-template-from-android-studio)

The use of `volatile` suggests they want thread-safety (although I'm not sure why since it appears to be a single-threaded app).

1. If thread-safety is needed then why isn't there a `synchronized` in the getInstance method?
2. If thread-safety is not needed, why is `volatile` used?

I understand there could be a use of `volatile` without `synchronized` in such multi-threaded cases as [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385763/uses-of-volatile-without-synchronization) but in our case we are making a singleton.

Thanks

Comment: Off the cuff, this looks like a mistake in the templates.